# Display Two columns at the same time using Cross Apply

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cross-apply

I have pretty much the same logic on the bottom but I am not able to put together to display two columns.

I am not sure how to combine two Cross Apply queries into one.

```
select


DateAdd(hour,hour_diff, ps)   punch_start
from [dbo].[Stage]
cross apply
(
values
( Try_Convert(datetime, punch_start) )
) x
(ps)
left join 
[dbo].[DIM] d on ps between d.start_dt and  d.end_dt

,
DateAdd(hour,hour_diff, ps1)  punch_end
from [dbo].[Stage]
cross apply
(
values
( Try_Convert(datetime, punch_end) )
) y
(ps1)
left join 
[dbo].[DIM] d on ps1 between d.start_dt and  d.end_dt


punch_start
Mar 29 2022  3:00AM
Mar 23 2022  6:28PM
Apr 11 2022  3:12AM
Apr  5 2022 10:18AM
Mar 30 2022  7:00AM
Apr  7 2022  2:57AM
Apr  6 2022  8:00PM
Mar 23 2022  2:44AM
Mar 24 2022 12:00PM
Apr 14 2022  7:18AM


punch_end
Mar 29 2022  7:50AM
Mar 23 2022  7:59PM
Apr 11 2022  9:33AM
Apr  5 2022  2:08PM
Mar 30 2022 10:39AM
Apr  7 2022  7:35AM
Apr  6 2022  9:32PM
Mar 23 2022  7:03AM
Mar 24 2022  7:01PM
Apr 14 2022  7:48AM
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih  I just added the sample data. Both data should display at the same time (next to each other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can try combining two-column in `VALUES`

```
SELECT
    DateAdd(hour,hour_diff, ps)  punch_start,
    DateAdd(hour,hour_diff, ps1)  punch_end
FROM [dbo].[Stage]
CROSS APPLY
(
    values (Try_Convert(datetime, punch_start),Try_Convert(datetime, punch_end))
) x (ps,ps1)
left join 
[dbo].[DIM] d on 
    ps between d.start_dt and  d.end_dt
OR 
    ps1 between d.start_dt and  d.end_dt
```

Comment: I am getting some syntax error inside CROSS APPLY ( ).  Incorrect syntax near ')'. I just fixed it. I had to delete extra (  ).  Thanks!

Comment: @D-Shih What is ps & ps1 here ?Just For my understanding.

Comment: @Roshan That are alias name for `CROSS APPLY ...VALUE` column here is a sample for you https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28c3944ca8f8d88d356b5dea7341ca32